# DL380 G4 dead after erasing NVRAM

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

Got a used HP ProLiant DL380 G4 server. It was at least able to start from an Ubuntu live CD a few days ago. When I connected the iLO-port to a router with DHCP server iLO 1.62 was accessibly using the web interface and SSH.

Cleared the NVRAM (the wrong way):

- unplugged power
- set S6 of system maintenance switch
- plugged power in again
- started server
- shut down server
- unplugged power
- unset S6
- plugged power in again
- started server with "Firmware Maintenance 8.5" in DVD drive

From this time I could not connect to iLO with web interface and SSH. The iLO does not get an DHCP IP while other computers when connected to the same router have no problem. Only the yellow iLO port LED is on. 
A monitor did not even wake up when connected to the video. No beeping. A USB key drive did not show activity when the server was turned on.

When off the iLO status LEDs flash like this:
- 1, 3, 4, 6, 8 together
- 5, 7 together
- 2 off

When starting the server this LEDs are on:
- 2, 8
- after about 15 s: 3, 4

In the User Guide HP writes "iLO diagnostic LEDs      Refer to the HP Integrated Lights-Out User Guide". But apart from a special case with LED 4 off I could not find further information there.

Does anybody know something about the meaning of the iLO diagnostic LEDs ?
Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trash it :) [Buy another for $75 (or less) on eBay.](http://www.ebay.com/csc/Servers-/11211/i.html?_sop=15&_from=R40&_nkw=dl380%20g4&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc)

Why did you clear the NVRAM? Was there a problem with the server after you were able to boot Ubuntu?

The normal approach for this is to leave the system powered off for some time... attempt power-on again.

For the ILO, you may not have an immediate solution.

I'd suggest the "[HP ProLiant DL380 Generation 4 Server Maintenance and Service Guide](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00687567/c00687567.pdf)" as the next step.

Oh, also this gem from the [ProLiant Troubleshooting Guide](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00300504/c00300504.pdf)...

[image: flow]

Comment: After one night without power iLO is up again as at the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad that worked for you!